# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Notification$Builder.setColor

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

```
final Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bwf_logo)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white)) // **exception raised at this line**
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setStyle(
                        new Notification.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(notificationMessage))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(
                        RingtoneManager
                                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setVibrate(vibrate).setContentText(notificationMessage);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

01-17 21:14:44.450: W/dalvikvm(27472): threadid=38: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41004318)
01-17 21:14:44.450: E/AndroidRuntime(27472): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService]
01-17 21:14:44.450: E/AndroidRuntime(27472): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Notification$Builder.setColor
01-17 21:14:44.450: E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at com.bwf.betswithfriends.GCMIntentService.gcmAlternateStakeNotification(GCMIntentService.java:109)
01-17 21:14:44.450: E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at com.bwf.betswithfriends.GCMIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMIntentService.java:51)
01-17 21:14:44.450: E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
01-17 21:14:44.450: E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 21:14:44.450: E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 21:14:44.450: E/AndroidRuntime(27472):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
01-17 21:14:44.560: D/dalvikvm(27472): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3520K, 16% free 22535K/26695K, paused 14ms+24ms, total 131ms
```

Support Library is up to date :-

[image]

Comment: Were you running on a pre-Lollipop Android?

Comment: Same error here. NotificationCompat.Builder().setColor() => FATAL EXCEPTION, NoSuchMethodError

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`setColor()` is new to API Level 21](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setColor%28int%29) and will not work on older devices.

I **strongly** recommend that you switch to `NotificationCompat.Builder`, as it will allow you to call `setColor()` and will simply skip that work on older devices.

Comment: NotificationCompat.Builder, I tried to use this but in this I am not getting setColor() method and my code is not getting compiled.

Comment: @Scorpion: Then your Android Support package that your project is using needs to be updated, as [`setColor()` is in the current edition of `NotificationCompat.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColor%28int%29).

Comment: I have updated everything using my SDK Manager and replaced the old Support package with updated one but still I am not getting the setColor() method.

Comment: @Scorpion: If you are using Eclipse, you also need to make sure that you have a fresh copy of the `support-v4` or `support-v13` Android library project in your workspace, that your app is leveraging as an Android library project. If you are using Android Studio, make sure that you are requesting version 21 or higher of the `support-v4` or `support-v13` artifacts.

Comment: I am using the fresh copy in project but still I am not getting the setColor method. Attached the image as well.

Comment: @Scorpion: *:: shrug ::* I just created a new project in Android Studio, pulling in a v21 edition of `support-v4`, and `setColor()` on `NotificationCompat.Builder` resolves just fine. I do not know what is different about your environment that would be causing your difficulties.